# Error accessing NOAA site using lat/long

Tags: url

I'm trying to retrieve weather data by latitude and longitude.  I've reviewed the API on the NOAA website and I believe I'm creating my URL as indicated.  However I get an error every time I try to look by lat/long.  I can retrieve based on zip code, but I need to use lat/long as there are foreign locations I need data for as well.

Here is the URL I am trying to access:
 http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-services/services/datasets/GHCND/locationsearch?latitude=35.59528&longitude=-82.55667token=XuynqsXFIGjQEXIshdoyFizBgrdZdwXO

Here is the API from their website, specific to the lat/long search:
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/cdows_locationsearch

and I get this error:

```
<cdoError>
<name>Internal Error</name>
<message>CDO Web Services error</message>
</cdoError>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?  Am I creating the URL incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `&` before `token`:

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-services/services/datasets/GHCND/locationsearch?latitude=35.59528&longitude=-82.55667&token=XuynqsXFIGjQEXIshdoyFizBgrdZdwXO

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to using web services!